# How to use 2checkout to fixed shipping address

Tags: php, 2checkout

I use 2checkout for the payment,fill in the shipping address on my own website,then jump to 2checkout checkout page,but it will fill in the shipping address again.It will cause the freight risk if someone reselect the shipping address.
I don't know why,please help me.
This is the parameters that need to transport.

```html
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>" />
  <input type='hidden' name='mode' value='2CO' >
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
  <input type='hidden' name='li_<?php echo $i; ?>_type' value='product' >
  <input type='hidden' name='li_<?php echo $i; ?>_name' value='<?php echo $product['name']; ?>' >
  <input type='hidden' name='li_<?php echo $i; ?>_product_id' value='<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>' >
  <input type='hidden' name='li_<?php echo $i; ?>_description' value='<?php echo $product['description']; ?>' >
  <input type='hidden' name='li_<?php echo $i; ?>_price' value='<?php echo $product['price']; ?>' >
  <input type='hidden' name='li_<?php echo $i; ?>_quantity' value='<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>' >
  <input type='hidden' name='li_<?php echo $i; ?>_tangible' value='Y' >
  <?php $i++; ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <input type='hidden' name='li_0_type' value='<?php echo $shipping; ?>' />
  <input type='hidden' name='li_0_name' value='<?php echo $shipping_name; ?>' />
  <input type='hidden' name='li_0_price' value='<?php echo $freight; ?>' />
  <input type="hidden" name="card_holder_name" value="<?php echo $card_holder_name; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="street_address" value="<?php echo $street_address; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />
  <input type='hidden' name='ship_name' value='<?php echo $ship_name;?>' >
  <input type="hidden" name="ship_street_address" value="<?php echo $ship_street_address; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ship_city" value="<?php echo $ship_city; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ship_state" value="<?php echo $ship_state; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ship_zip" value="<?php echo $ship_zip; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ship_country" value="<?php echo $ship_country; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $tco_currency; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="<?php echo $lang; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="x_receipt_link_url" value="<?php echo $return_url; ?>" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="right">
      <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" class="button" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[The shipping address on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKhvD.jpg)

[The 2checkout checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyvyD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the 2Checkout Answer in the next link, may be it will helps you, the redirect is not only because of the shipping address, remove your cookies, send all the required fields and check on on real account.

[2Checkout inline checkout redirects to the full checkout page for some countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808388/2checkout-inline-checkout-redirects-to-the-full-checkout-page-for-some-countries/35764913#35764913)